# Why didn't Pandorica's restoration field bring back Dalek in the Roman era?

Tags: doctor-who

In season 5 finale of *Doctor Who*, just after Rory freed The Doctor from the Pandorica, The Doctor saw a Dalek's shadow and it was under high intensity light. I just analyzed that portion of the episode and I concluded that that was the light from the Pandorica because the moments before, there was no light there.

Why didn't that light bring that Dalek back into the existence that time?

Comment: You really take Doctor Who seriously

Answer (score 1):

The reason the light didnt bring the Dalek back to life that time was that the pandorica was not open long enough to restore it to life. The pandorica forces what is inside it to stay alive, it is like radiation a little exposure is harmless but when forced on to something for a period of time the effects will take place, they didnt close the pandorica letting out the restoration energy focusing on the Dalek bringing it back instead of taking the doctor out and putting Amy in and having 2-3 bodies blocking the light and energy from focusing on the dalek